# Getting different output with append and +

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

> > > ## Code to get k step separated set of the given string
> > >
> > > s = 'AABCAAADA'
> > > k = 3
> > > samp = []
> > > for i in range(0, len(s), k):
> > > samp.append(subsamp)
> > >
> > > ## Using samp +=  subsamp gives different output
> > >
> > > for i in samp:
> > > j = (sorted(set(i), key = i.index))
> > > print("".join(j))

Comment: The thing you want is to get all the characters in sets of k digits, right?

Comment: AB
CA
AD
Should be the output for the given input

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As far as I know both append and '+' in a string do the same job,  but the code written above is having different output with (samp += subsamp) and (samp.append(subsamp)
So I just wanted to understand that why the outputs are different.